# Android app for learning to read in Georgian

Tags: android, educational, language

I'd like once to learn the basics of Georgian, but I was stuck with the alphabet. I've found some apps that were providing example Georgian sentences with transliterations, but those were only examples. Most e-books switch to Georgian alphabet only immediately after introducing alphabet.

I'm not exactly sure what would be the best for teaching alphabet, but for sure there should be a lot of simple texts, as well as geographical names, with transliteration. The learning of alphabet should also include some interactions, like quizes (letting me to choose correct transliteration, for example).

Is there such an app for Android?

Answer (score 3):

[AnkiDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki&hl=en) is a flashcard app that helps you memorize vocabulary/etc efficiently.

It has 11 decks for Georgian:
https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/georgian
For instance **Georgian Alphabet** and **Georgian Useful Expressions**.

Free, Open Source.
4.5 stars, 850k users.
Disclaimer: I (and other volunteers) maintain AnkiDroid.